# Удалить из предложения слова, целиком составленные из вхождений не более чем двух букв

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Начал изучать С++, сижу на Windows forms.

Суть задачи

Пользователь вводит текст в textbox, после нажатия на кнопку, из этого текста должны удалиться все слова , целиком составленные из вхождений не более чем двух букв и результат выведется в мою заданную область.

Я вроде понял алгоритм решения,(
преобразовал в массив,теперь нужно пробежаться циклом по массиву и и если встречается слово с 2-мя или меньше символами, удалить его,)  но не могу реализовать, появляется много ошибок

Вот код

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        String^ str = textBox1->Text;


        char Mass= str[0];
        //тут должен быть цикл

        label3->Text = str;
```

Благодарен за помощь

```
String^ line = textBox1->Text;
        String^ reg = R"((\w+))";
        array<String^>^ arrLines = Regex::Split(line, reg);


        List<String^>^ lines = gcnew List<String^>();


        label3->Text = "";
        for (int i(0); i < arrLines->Length; i++)

        {
            if (!Regex::IsMatch(arrLines[i], R"((\s+))") && arrLines[i]->Length > 2)


                lines->Add(arrLines[i]);

                label3->Text += arrLines[i] + " ";

        }   
все равно не работает(
```

Comment: Это не C++, это C++/CLI. Это совершенно разные языки. Если хотите изучать действительно C++, то забудьте о WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам уже посоветовали - это не C++, а C++\CLI. Тем не менее:

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Text::RegularExpressions;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Text;
/// ..... etc
{
        textBox1->Text = "аааааа bbbbb ccc dd eeeee  z    fffffff     y       ggggggggg " +
            "hhhhh  iiiiiii  " +
            "jjjjjj";

        String^ line = textBox1->Text; 
        label1->Text = "";
        String^ reg = R"((\w+))";
        array<String^>^ arrLines = Regex::Split(line, reg);
        for (int i(0); i < arrLines->Length; i++)
        {
            if (arrLines[i]->Length > 2)
                label1->Text += arrLines[i] + " ";
        }
}
```

Comment: array<String^>^ arrLines = Regex::Split(line, reg); недостаточно аргументов для шаблон класса "std::array"
как можно исправить?

Comment: @propane67 - повторю еще раз: C++ и C++/CLI - **разные** языки. `std::array` есть в первом, но его нет во втором. PS: Недаром одной из практик хорошего кодирования на C++ считается не открывать пространства имен. Во многих конторах за это бьют ногами. PPS: уберите из своего кода `using namespace std`. PPPS: В C++/CLI открытие неймспейсов - нормальная практика.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за разжевывание , Но у меня еще один вопрос
Судя по коду все подходящие слова записываются в lines?

Comment: @propane67 да, это лист строк

Comment: @Range А как вывести lines в область label->Text? такое ощущение, что он не видит ничего в lines

Comment: @propane67 Не проблема - Вы можете заменить массив строк на просто строку String^, и выполнять конкатенацию(+=, Concat, Insert, и т.д.), и уже эту строку вывести на форму.

Comment: label3->Text += (Convert::ToString(arrLines[i]));
Добавил эту строку в цикл, но все равно не получается то, что нужно
В чем ошибка?

Comment: @propane67 во-первых, зачем Вы конвертируете строку в строку? Вот: label3->Text += arrLines[i] + " "; Также, надо добавить пробел для разделения. Во - вторых, перед добавлением текста label3 следует очистить от предыдущего текста(возможно, он есть). Обнулите текст в ручную (= ""). И в - третьих, рано Вы залезли в фреймворки, Вы не знаете еще основ. Рекомендую всё же изучать C++, причем с начала.

Comment: Добавил эту строкку в код, но все равно не получается удалить слова, выводит просто все содержимое, много чего менял, не получается. В чем проблема может быть?
код в заголовке(

Comment: @propane67 обновил свой пост, не понимаю, что может быть сложно в переделке кода. Пару строк ведь поменять.